# Can I backup only the iPhone keychain?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, password, keychain

I need to be able to backup my keychain separately from the normal backup process.

My core issue is that I have forgotten/lost my iPhone backup password.

I want to be able to create usable backups going forward.

Of course I have lost all my old backups. Water under the bridge.

I just want to create a new backup password, and that appears to require resetting all security and losing the keychain, Wifi passwords, and Bluetooth connections.

So I would like to be able to back those systems up, if possible.

Does someone know how?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  As we strongly prefer one question per question, I’ve made an edit to remove what seemed the side questions. Why not use iCloud backup and turn off all the buckets except keychain? Also - are you backing up to a computer or iCloud?